# Segue not firing from TableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift

I've set up segue from `UIButton` which works OK, but a segue i've set up on a `TableViewCell` does not work.

The `TableViewCell` highlights on touch, but the segue does not fire off.
The `TableViewCell` is highligting in grey, but I set it to Blue.

The segue is a selection push segue.

I've done this in Objective-C many times with no problem, why dosn't it work in Swift.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: I think the grey cell thing is a beta issue - I've seen it too. Raise a bug with Apple for this one: http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean that prepareForSegue() never gets called for it?

Comment: Yes the prepareForSegue never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by changing the following :-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
  let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"categorycell")
}
```

changed to :-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell?
{
        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categorycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
}
```

and the segue now fires.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.